# HMACSHA256 in C# vs node.js

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, cryptography

I am generating a hash string in C# and node.js but keep getting two different results...

In C#:

```
byte[] secretKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String('some_secret_key');
byte[] requestValuesSignature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes('teststring');
HMACSHA256 testHash = new HMACSHA256(secretKeyBytes);

byte[] = hashedBytes = testHash.ComputeHash(requestValuesSignature);
string hash1 = Convert.ToBAse64String(hashedBytes);

Console.WriteLine(hash1);
```

In Node.js:

```
var hash2 = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', 'some_secret_key').update('teststring', 'utf8').digest('base64');
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It helps if you provide results, add to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
byte[] secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes('some_secret_key');
```

because the JS implementation does the same, it just gets the bytes from the key string, which does not need to be a base64 string but can be any string.

EDIT:

As you can't change C# side, you have to do the same (possibly wrong) behaviour on the nodejs side, i.e. decode the base64 string before it is used as secret.

```
var mykey = new Buffer('some_secret_key', 'base64').toString();
var hash2 = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', mykey).update('teststring', 'utf8').digest('base64');
```

Be aware, both sides will fail, if the secret is not a valid base64 string (which is allowed!)

Comment: i can't change anything on the C# side since it's code from another team.. i'd have to change stuff on the node.js side..

Comment: @user1547174 it is best to add additional informatin such as this the the question.

Answer (score -4):

Answer - on the C# side, change utf8 to ASCIIEncoding!

Comment: First of all, you said, you could not change anything on the c# side?? Second this answer is just plain wrong.